# Convert/Format DateString from NSUserdefaults

Tags: ios, string, date, format, nsuserdefaults

I tried to format a String from NSUserDefaults, which holds a Date. 
The result is (null). 
My question is: Is there a way to convert this String into a date to format it, or is there a better way?

My Code:

```
NSString *c = [prefs objectForKey:@"expiration_date_full"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss"];            
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];            
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:c];           

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@   Noch gültig bis: %@", a, b, dateFromString];
```

Comment: do you have values in c string?

Comment: yes, in c there is string like 2014-22-11 18:06:35 +0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store an NSDate in NSUserDefaults without conversion. That is, NSDate is one of the types supported by PLISTs. You can check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

change your date format

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
   NSDate* myTime = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"07-22-2014"];
    NSLog(@"%@",myTime);
```